# Spring boot controller - Download Multipart and JSON to DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I need get a JAVA Object (DTO) with a MultipartFile in a Spring Controller

I tried different ways, like use of `produces = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}` but nothing works.

The "DTO" to get is:

```
public class TodoDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String description;

    private Boolean status;

    private MultipartFile image;

    ...
}
```

And the controller method is:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<List<TodoDTO>> getAll() {

    ResponseEntity<List<TodoDTO>> response;

    try {
        response = new ResponseEntity<List<TodoDTO>>(todoService.getAll(), HttpStatus.FOUND); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return response;
}
```

I will expect to get entire object, with Multipart and the other properties. But the response in Postman is:

```
"status": 406,
"error": "Not Acceptable",
"message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
```

Comment: Just to make sure - you have a GET method that you sent it a (multipart) file as an input?

Comment: No, I need to return the multipart